# Finding anchor text when there are tags there

Tags: python, regex

I want to find the text between a pair of <a> tags that link to a given site

Here's the re string that I'm using to find the content:

```
r'''(<a([^<>]*)href=("|')(http://)?(www\.)?%s([^'"]*)("|')([^<>]*)>([^<]*))</a>''' % our_url
```

The result will be something like this:

```
r'''(<a([^<>]*)href=("|')(http://)?(www\.)?stackoverflow.com([^'"]*)("|')([^<>]*)>([^<]*))</a>'''
```

This is great for most links but it errors with a link with tags within it. I tried changing the final part of the regex from:

```
([^<]*))</a>'''
```

to:

```
(.*))</a>'''
```

But that just got everything on the page after the link, which I don't want. Are there any suggestions on what I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
[^<>]*
```

Try:

```
((?!</a).)*
```

In other words, match any character that isn't the start of a `</a` sequence.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'<a.+href=[\'|\"](.+)[\'|\"].*?>(.+)</a>', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> link = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603199/finding-anchor-text-when-there-are-tags-there">Finding anchor text when there are tags there</a>'
>>> re.match(pattern, link).group(1)
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603199/finding-anchor-text-when-there-are-tags-there'
>>> re.match(pattern, link).group(2)
'Finding anchor text when there are tags there'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not use a regex - use an HTML parser like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: Seems a bit heavyweight for such a simple problem

Comment: Never.  HTML is highly irregular -- browsers are require to tolerate a large number of errors.  Beautiful Soup can better processor irregular HTML than regexes can.

Answer (score 1):

Do a non greedy search i.e.

```
(.*?)
```

Comment: It matches only until the tag within the anchor text